# How can I integrate my regular login sessions with Facebook login sessions?

Tags: php, facebook, session, authentication

Currently when I login to my website via Facebook I still can't access restricted pages because I haven't set a session. My question is how do I go about integrating my regular sessions with Facebook so that they are one in the same?

I have this code on my index.php page

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//mysite/channel.php', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
      // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
      // have logged in to the app.    
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      FB.login();
    } else {
      FB.login();
    }
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

My regular session code is on another page and is set when a password input and username input matches a username and password in my database.

Comment: If you're only using facebook for login then it might be worth you looking at the [PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) you can set it up easily and login with `$facebook->getLoginUrl($params)` I find it much easier to handle everything server side when logging in

Comment: _“My regular session code is on another page and is set when a password input and username input matches a username and password in my database.”_ – well then simply do the same thing when you have verified the login via Facebook – where’s the _actual_ problem in doing that?